# MFC: How do I change the background color of the whole editBox?

Tags: c++, mfc

My questions is similar to:
[win32 : display editbox with black color in text area on windows mobile 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328026/win32-display-editbox-with-black-color-in-text-area-on-windows-mobile-5)

However I'm using MFC which doesn't have the same solution available as the one in the above link.

**How do I change the background color of the whole background, not just the background behind the text of an edit box?**

Below is my code, that only changes the background behind the text, not the whole background of the edit box.

```
HBRUSH CGadgetStandardDialog::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CStandardDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255,255,255));

    return hbr;
}
```

Comment: Maybe overriding `OnEraseBkgnd` would help.

Comment: i feel like that is a good direction to go, but i don't know how to proceed..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to calling SetBkColor you need to return a HBRUSH of the desired background color. So create a brush earlier (say, in the dialog constructor):

```
m_brBack.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
```

And then return that brush when called for the control of interest:

```
HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_EDIT2)
{
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0,255,0));
    hbr = m_brBack;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename your button resource like below.

```
CButton  m_StopButtonto;
```

to

```
CMFCButton  m_StopButton;
```

Change some visible features

```
// Set the background color for the button text.
  m_StopButton.SetFaceColor(RGB(255,0,0),true);
  m_StopButton.SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,255));
  // Set the tooltip of the button.
  m_StopButton.SetTooltip(_T("This is my Stop Button!"));
```

I tried this solution for button and it worked for me. I guess it will work for the other components.